# Probability question with generalities

Tags: probability

just struggling with a probability question, looking for some guidance or a solution method.

There are two envelopes containing money, one labelled H and the other T. Inside each envelope is a sum of money between 1 and 2000 (whole) dollars, with the two amounts being different. A fair coin is tossed and you receive H if it's heads, and T if it's tails. You look at the money in the envelope, and you swap the envelope if after drawing a number uniformly from the set {1,2,..,2000} and if the number is greater or equal to the amount in the first envelope, I switch envelopes. If not, I keep the original envelope.

Assume that the amount in the H envelope is h dollars, and the amount in the
T envelope is t dollars, with h < t (without loss of generality). If you use the
strategy above, find the probability that you end up with $t, that is, the
larger amount of money.

Also find the minimum probability that you end up with the larger amount with this strategy.

I believe the answer to the first section involves finding the probability of having T, and then not swapping and adding the probability of having H, and then swapping:

$$ \frac{H(2000-H)}{2}+ \frac{T(T-2000)}{2}$$

Is this correct?

And would finding the second answer involve differentiating this formula and equating it to 0?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The expression in your question cannot be recognized as a probability. Btw, what are $H$ and $T$ in it? They cannot be recognized as numbers (this in contrast with $h$ and $t$).

Answer (score 1):

Let $H$ denote the event that head is thrown, and $T$ the event that tail is trown. Let $X$ denote the number that is drawn. Then you are looking for: $$\Pr(H\cap\{X\geq h\})+\Pr(T\cap\{X<t\})$$

Note that $H$ and $\{X\geq h\}$ are independent, and also $T$ and $\{X<t\}$ are independent.

If you work this out properly then you end up with probability:

> $$\frac12\left[1+\frac{t-h}{2000}\right]\geq\frac12\left[1+\frac1{2000}\right]$$